# Do or don't submit the comment-feed of your blog?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, sitemap

A commentsfeed (of a blog) might serve perfectly as a commentssitemap. I'm wondering if it's a good idea to submit this feed to Google's webmaster tools.

What are the pros & cons?

Comment: You're already submitting a feed which links to the post page, Google likes the post more than the comments, I don't see a need to submit a comment feed. If you're Zappos with more comments than product copy, reviews included you may consider using it.

Answer (score 3):

I would answer **no** to this question, for the following reasons:

1. RSS as an alternative for XML Sitemap is just that - an *alternative*
2. The comments feed is just a list of fragment references ([the bit in the URL after the #](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1.1)) to one page, as opposed to a list of unique page URLs - which is the intent of a sitemap.
3. I would suggest that comments aren't (normally) the strongest value area of a page - you would hope that the actual content being commented on was, so there doesn't seem to be much value highlighting the low-value are to search engines.